# Access a coldfusion variable without knowing the name

Tags: coldfusion

Is there a syntax in coldfusion that will let me do that following?

```
<cfif DataSet2.RecordCount gt 0 > 
  <cfset append = #ArrayAppend(DataSet2Results,VAL(DataSet2.RecordCount))# >
</cfif>
```

Replacing the '2' in each case with an variable name (an index in a loop in this case). 
So it would look like:

```
<cfif DataSet#index#.RecordCount gt 0 > 
      <cfset append = #ArrayAppend(DataSet#index#Results,VAL(DataSet#index#.RecordCount))# >
    </cfif>
```

I know I can do a two dimensional array for this, but it would save me a slice of time if this can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Variable Names Coldfusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719947/dynamic-variable-names-coldfusion)

Comment: My solution was slightly different, I posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question. I used Variables["DataSet#index#"].recordcount and so on.